# How to set maxDF to pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer even though there was no maxDF parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

My program was already working nicely using CountVectorizer from pyspark.ml package. But, this CountVectorizer doesn't have maxDF parameter like CountVectorizer in sklearn.feature_extraction.text package which remove term that appear too frequent in document list. Is there any way to apply that to CountVectorizer from pyspark.ml package?

Answer (score 1):

`maxDF` `Param` has been included in Spark 2.4.0 (not released officially yet, but already available from PyPi and Apache Foundation archives):

- [SPARK-23166](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23166) - *Add maxDF Parameter to CountVectorizer*
- [SPARK-23615](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23615) - *Add maxDF Parameter to Python CountVectorizer*

and [can be used as any other `Param`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a33655348c4066d9c1d8ad2055aadfbc892ba7fd/python/pyspark/ml/tests.py#L700-L723):

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(maxDF=99)
```

or

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer().setMaxDF(99)
```

To use it you'll have to either update Spark to 2.4.0 or later, or backport the corresponding PRs and [build Spark from source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html).